# Loading non valid xml in Calabash / xproc

Tags: validation, input, calabash, xproc

I am trying to create a routine for validating xhtml documents. I use xproc which I run in Calabash. In is an xhtml document. This document may not be valid.

For testing I edit an xhtml document. I simply delete a  and introduce an error. This is the error I hope to detect when I validate the document.

In order to validate I use , I supply a schema, and I output the result of the validation in a new file.

But if the input file is not valid in the first place xproc/Calabash stops. The error message is basically an error message from Saxon pointing out that the  is missing. But I wanted the validation output in my output file. How do I do that?

```
<p:input port="source" primary="true"/>

<p:load name="xml-doc" href="'input.xhtml'"/>       

<p:validate-with-xml-schema name="validate">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:pipe port="result" step="xml-doc"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:with-option name="assert-valid" select="'false'"/>
    <p:with-option name="mode" select="'lax'"/>
    <p:input port="schema">
        <p:document href="xhtml-schema.xsd"/>
    </p:input> 
</p:validate-with-xml-schema>

<p:store name="valid-store">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:pipe port="result" step="validate"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:with-option name="href" select="'output.xml'"/>
</p:store>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not clear what exactly is Saxon complaining about, but I assume that it cannot find the input XHTML file. You wrap the file name in single quotes in `p:load/@href`, which is not correct. When you use the attribute-based shortcut form for options, the value of the attribute is taken as-is and is not interpreted as an XPath expression (which is the case when you use the long `p:with-option` form).